# directed gradient in svg's path element

Tags: javascript, html, dom, svg

I'm writing a simple webpage that displays a graph and shows dependencies. I found an unexpected behavior in how `path` elements are rendered within `svg`.

Here's the full HTML of the example:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <svg id="svgConnections" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="width: 300px; height: 120px">
            <defs>
                <linearGradient id="grad1" >
                <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:yellow;stop-opacity:1" />
                <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:red;stop-opacity:1" />
                </linearGradient>
            </defs>            
            <path d="M40,40 L100,100 Z" stroke="url(#grad1)" strokeWidth="1px" />
            <path d="M200,100 L140,40 Z" stroke="url(#grad1)" strokeWidth="1px" />
        </svg>
    </body>
</html>
```

The same example is on https://jsfiddle.net/4fLjm0e2/

What bugs me is that the first line, which goes from top left to bottom right corner, looks exactly like the second line, which goes "in reverse": from bottom right corner to the top left.

**How do I make the path always start with yellow and end with red?**

Comment: I've just read the doc but I have not found anything that could help you easily. One solution is to set `x1`, `x2`, `y1`, `y1` (attribute of `<linearGraient>`) dependently on the orientation of the line, but I hope there's a simple solution to this.

Answer (score 4):

> This is not a bug. This is problem in understanding.

The default behavior of a linear gradient is to transition along a horizontal line from the left side of an object to its right side. It doesn't matter if you draw a path from left to right or from right to left. In both cases gradient will appear as from left to right as per default settings.

Consider the demo below:

```html
<svg width="120" height="120" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="grad1" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:yellow;stop-opacity:1" />
      <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:red;stop-opacity:1" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <g stroke-width="2">
    <path d="M10,40 L110,40 Z" stroke="url(#grad1)" />
    <path d="M110,70 L10,70 Z" stroke="url(#grad1)" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

If you wants the transition of colors to occur across a vertical line or a line at an angle, you must specify the line's starting point with the `x1` and
`y1` attributes and its ending points with the `x2` and `y2` attributes.

Rather than duplicate the stops into each `<linearGradient>` element, we'll use the `xlink:href` attribute to refer to the original gradient. The stops will be inherited, but the x- and y-coordinates will be overridden by each individual gradient.

```
<linearGradient id="grad1" x1="0" y1="0" x2="1" y2="1">
  <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,255,0);stop-opacity:1" />
  <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,0,0);stop-opacity:1" />
</linearGradient>
<linearGradient id="grad2" xlink:href="#grad1" x1="1" y1="1" x2="0" y2="0"></linearGradient>
```

Extending the above example:

```html
<svg width="120" height="120" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="grad1" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,255,0);stop-opacity:1" />
      <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,0,0);stop-opacity:1" />
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="grad2" xlink:href="#grad1" x1="120" y1="0" x2="0" y2="0"></linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <g stroke-width="2">
    <path d="M10,40 L110,40" stroke="url(#grad1)" />
    <path d="M110,70 L10,70 Z" stroke="url(#grad2)" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

As in your example, you are using diagonal paths so we need to override `x1`, `y1`, `x2` and `y2` attribute of both `<linearGradient>` elements.

- These values on the first `<linearGradient>` element will override the default left to right settings to produce a diagonal gradient from top left to the right bottom.
- While on the `<linearGradient>` element these values will change the direction of gradient i.e from bottom to top.

Now we can apply these gradients to the respective paths.

```html
<svg width="300" height="120" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="grad1" x1="0" y1="0" x2="1" y2="1">
      <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,255,0);stop-opacity:1" />
      <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,0,0);stop-opacity:1" />
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="grad2" xlink:href="#grad1" x1="1" y1="1" x2="0" y2="0"></linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <g stroke-width="2">
    <path d="M40,40 L100,100 Z" stroke="url(#grad1)" />
    <path d="M200,100 L140,40 Z" stroke="url(#grad2)" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

***Note:*** This [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14633363/can-i-apply-a-gradient-along-an-svg-path) can be useful in context with the current problem.