# svg multiple color on circle stroke

Tags: svg, colors, gradient, curve

I want to create a rainbow circle, like the picture below:

[image]

How can I draw the curved and multiple color stop gradient?

Here's my current code:

```html
<svg width="500" height="500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <defs>
    <linearGradient id="test">
    <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#f00"/>
    <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#0ff"/>
    </linearGradient>    
    </defs>    
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="none" stroke="url(#test)" stroke-width="6"/>    
</svg>
```

Answer (score 62, accepted):

This approach won't work.  SVG doesn't have conical gradients.  To simulate the effect, you would have to fake it with a large number of small line segments.  Or some similar technique.

**Update:**

Here is an example. I approximate the 360deg of hue with six paths. Each path contains an arc which covers 60deg of the circle.  I use a linear gradient to interpolate the colour from the start to the end of each path.  It's not perfect (you can see some discontinuities where the coloursmeet ) but it would possibly fool most people.  You could increase the accuracy by using more than six segments.

```html
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="-10 -10 220 220">
      <defs>
        <linearGradient id="redyel" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" x1="0" y1="0" x2="1" y2="1">
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#ff0000"/>   
            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#ffff00"/>   
        </linearGradient>
        <linearGradient id="yelgre" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="1">
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#ffff00"/>   
            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#00ff00"/>   
        </linearGradient>
        <linearGradient id="grecya" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" x1="1" y1="0" x2="0" y2="1">
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#00ff00"/>   
            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#00ffff"/>   
        </linearGradient>
        <linearGradient id="cyablu" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" x1="1" y1="1" x2="0" y2="0">
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#00ffff"/>   
            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#0000ff"/>   
        </linearGradient>
        <linearGradient id="blumag" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" x1="0" y1="1" x2="0" y2="0">
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#0000ff"/>   
            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#ff00ff"/>   
        </linearGradient>
        <linearGradient id="magred" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" x1="0" y1="1" x2="1" y2="0">
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#ff00ff"/>   
            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#ff0000"/>   
        </linearGradient>
      </defs>
    
      <g fill="none" stroke-width="15" transform="translate(100,100)">
        <path d="M 0,-100 A 100,100 0 0,1 86.6,-50" stroke="url(#redyel)"/>
        <path d="M 86.6,-50 A 100,100 0 0,1 86.6,50" stroke="url(#yelgre)"/>
        <path d="M 86.6,50 A 100,100 0 0,1 0,100" stroke="url(#grecya)"/>
        <path d="M 0,100 A 100,100 0 0,1 -86.6,50" stroke="url(#cyablu)"/>
        <path d="M -86.6,50 A 100,100 0 0,1 -86.6,-50" stroke="url(#blumag)"/>
        <path d="M -86.6,-50 A 100,100 0 0,1 0,-100" stroke="url(#magred)"/>
      </g>
    </svg>
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Weytu/

**Update 2:**

For those that want more than six segments, here is some javascript that will produce a wheel with any number of segments that you wish.

```js
function makeColourWheel(numSegments)
{
    if (numSegments <= 0)
        numSegments = 6;
    if (numSegments > 360)
        numSegments = 360;

    var  svgns = xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
    var  svg = document.getElementById("colourwheel");
    var  defs = svg.getElementById("defs");
    var  paths = svg.getElementById("paths");

    var  radius = 100;
    var  stepAngle = 2 * Math.PI / numSegments;

    var  lastX = 0;
    var  lastY = -radius;
    var  lastAngle = 0;
    
    for (var i=1; i<=numSegments; i++)
    {
        var  angle = i * stepAngle;

        // Calculate this arc end point
        var x = radius * Math.sin(angle);
        var y = -radius * Math.cos(angle);
        // Create a path element
        var arc = document.createElementNS(svgns, "path");
        arc.setAttribute("d", "M " + lastX.toFixed(3) + "," + lastY.toFixed(3)
                              + " A 100,100 0 0,1 " + x.toFixed(3) + "," + y.toFixed(3));
        arc.setAttribute("stroke", "url(#wheelseg" + i + ")");
        // Append it to our SVG
        paths.appendChild(arc);
        
        // Create a gradient for this segment
        var grad = document.createElementNS(svgns, "linearGradient");
        grad.setAttribute("id", "wheelseg"+i);
        grad.setAttribute("gradientUnits", "userSpaceOnUse");
        grad.setAttribute("x1", lastX.toFixed(3));
        grad.setAttribute("y1", lastY.toFixed(3));
        grad.setAttribute("x2", x.toFixed(3));
        grad.setAttribute("y2", y.toFixed(3));
        // Make the 0% stop for this gradient
        var stop = document.createElementNS(svgns, "stop");
        stop.setAttribute("offset", "0%");
        hue = Math.round(lastAngle * 360 / Math.PI / 2);
        stop.setAttribute("stop-color", "hsl(" + hue + ",100%,50%)");
        grad.appendChild(stop);
        // Make the 100% stop for this gradient
        stop = document.createElementNS(svgns, "stop");
        stop.setAttribute("offset", "100%");
        hue = Math.round(angle * 360 / Math.PI / 2);
        stop.setAttribute("stop-color", "hsl(" + hue + ",100%,50%)");
        grad.appendChild(stop);
        // Add the gradient to the SVG
        defs.appendChild(grad);

        // Update lastx/y
        lastX = x;
        lastY = y;
        lastAngle = angle;
    }
}


makeColourWheel(60);
```

```html
<svg id="colourwheel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="-10 -10 220 220">
  <defs id="defs">
  </defs>

  <g id="paths" fill="none" stroke-width="15" transform="translate(100,100)">
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: any example please? I just want to do exactly like the picture shown, size is no matter.

Comment: Updated with an example.

Comment: how do you implement a new segment?

Comment: You would need to calculate and add extra arc paths based on where you wanted your extra arc(s) to start and finish.  The advantage of the hexagon shape I've used here is that it made calculating those coords - and the gradients - fairly easy.

Comment: I've updated the answer with some JS to generate wheels.

Answer (score 17):

You can use the conic-gradient to solve it:

```css
.color-wheel {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 25px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: conic-gradient(red, yellow, lime, aqua, blue, magenta, red);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: auto;
}

.color-wheel::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  padding: 75px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="color-wheel"></div>
```

But this is currently only supported in Chrome. Take a look here for more information: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-conic-gradients

I also built javascript/svg solution which can solve it easily:

```js
const resolution = 1;
const outerRadius = 100;
const innerRadius = 75;

function polarToCartesian(centerX, centerY, radius, angleInDegrees) {
    const angleInRadians = (angleInDegrees - 90) * Math.PI / 180.0;

    return {
        x: centerX + radius * Math.cos(angleInRadians),
        y: centerY + radius * Math.sin(angleInRadians)
    };
}

function describeArc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle) {
    const start = polarToCartesian(x, y, radius, endAngle);
    const end = polarToCartesian(x, y, radius, startAngle);

    const arcSweep = endAngle - startAngle <= 180 ? '0' : '1';

    const d = [
        'M', start.x, start.y,
        'A', radius, radius, 0, arcSweep, 0, end.x, end.y,
        'L', x, y,
        'L', start.x, start.y
    ].join(' ');

    return d;
}

function generateConicGradiant(radius, resolution, target) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 360 * resolution; i++) {
        const path = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'path');

        path.setAttribute(
            "d",
            describeArc(
                radius,
                radius,
                radius,
                i / resolution,
                (i + 2) / resolution
            )
        );
        path.setAttribute('fill', 'hsl(' + (i / resolution) + ', 100%, 50%)');

        target.appendChild(path);
    } 
}

function generateOverlay(outerRadius, innerRadius, target) {
    const circle = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'circle');

    circle.setAttribute('cx', outerRadius);
    circle.setAttribute('cy', outerRadius);
    circle.setAttribute('r', innerRadius);
    circle.setAttribute('fill', 'white');

    target.appendChild(circle);
}

var root = document.getElementById('color-wheel');

generateConicGradiant(outerRadius, resolution, root);
generateOverlay(outerRadius, innerRadius, root);
```

```css
#color-wheel {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 200" version="1.1" id="color-wheel"></svg>
```

Comment: It's now supported on Firefox 83+!

Answer (score 1):

to improve oVi's answer: here you can set `diameter` and `stroke-width` to exact pixel sizes

```css
.color-wheel {
  --diameter: 160px;
  --stroke-width: 20px;
  position: relative;
  width: var(--diameter); height: var(--diameter);
}

.color-wheel > .color-circle {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; top: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
  background: conic-gradient(red, orange, yellow, lime, green, turquoise, blue, purple, red); /* four color system */
}

.color-wheel > .inner-circle {
  --inner-diameter: calc(var(--diameter) - 2 * var(--stroke-width));
  --margin: calc(-0.5 * var(--inner-diameter));
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%; top: 50%;
  width: var(--inner-diameter); height: var(--inner-diameter);
  margin-left: var(--margin); margin-top: var(--margin);
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: white;
}

.color-wheel > .overlay {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; top: 0;
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="color-wheel">
  <div class="color-circle"></div>
  <div class="inner-circle"></div>
  <div class="overlay">
    hello world.
    this is a pure CSS color ring : )
  </div>
</div>
```