# D3 fill color using custom scale

Tags: d3.js, charts, data-visualization

I have this code and i'd like to color the arc relatively to the value, passing a range of two colors (i.e. ['#f00', '#ff0]).

I can't find a way to declare a scale that builds me the right colors.

And i can't find anything on docs either...

This is the codepen where i would like to implement this

https://codepen.io/adeveloperdiary/pen/OydzpG

This is how i tried with no success

```js
 const colorRange = ['#f00', '#0f0'];
 
 const colorScale = d3.scaleOrdinal()
    .range([0, 100])
    .domain(colorRange);
    
 console.log(colorScale(75));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.2.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Do you want the arc to be full red at 1%, and full blue when it's 99%, or do you want it to be a gradient from red to blue?

Comment: Gradient, i want the color to depend from the value

Comment: like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18206361/svg-multiple-color-on-circle-stroke)?

Comment: Nope, this is a gradient. i need that if it's 100% the fill is #0f0 and if for example is 50% it's something in between #f00 and #0f0..

Comment: Yeah, when it's full it's like the gradient (forgot my old comment, I misread). I didn't understand the question the first time, sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a linear scale, not an ordinal scale. Also, swap the domain and range:

```js
const colorRange = ['#f00', '#0f0'];

const colorScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 100])
  .range(colorRange);

console.log(colorScale(75));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.2.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Here is the CodePen you linked with that scale (using D3 v3): https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RzNYvy