# SVG - Apply conic gradient to SVG using CSS

Tags: css, xml, svg, gradient, conic-gradients

Modern versions of Chrome and Firefox support conic gradients using CSS https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/conic-gradient().

SVG doesn't support conic gradients, so would it be possible to apply conic gradients to SVG paths using CSS?

I would like to apply a gradient to a line path.
Example:

```xml
<path d="m107.35 144.8a14.78 14.78 0 0 1-10.451-4.3288" style="fill:none;stroke-width:3.2844"/>
```

I would like something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54594553/5507535 but in SVG.

Comment: what kind of path? can you be more specific

Comment: @TemaniAfif I updated the question with an example path.

Comment: so you want a pie chart at the end?

Comment: some related questions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60586691/8620333/ https://stackoverflow.com/a/56799618/8620333 / https://stackoverflow.com/a/57144254/8620333

Comment: No, it's not possible.

Comment: See https://github.com/w3c/svgwg/issues/785