# SVG radial gradient has small spaces between elements

Tags: svg, radial-gradients

I needed to add a radial / conical gradient into an SVG circle. Unfortunately, there is no support for that on the standard: https://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Advanced_Gradients#Conical_gradient

So, I went for a solution similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18210763 but instead of using multiple colors, I use the same color with an alpha variation.

Mi final result ended like this:

```
<g fill="none" stroke-width="8" transform="translate(-49,-10) scale(1.2) rotate(0, 125, 50)" opacity="1">
                                <path d="M127.5593032836914,78.30342873930931 C124.73236846923828,78.30342873930931 122.4406967163086,76.50826272368431 122.4406967163086,74.29380044341087 C122.4406967163086,72.07933816313744 124.73236846923828,70.28415688872337 127.5593032836914,70.28415688872337 V78.30342873930931 z" fill="#23B26D"
                                      transform="scale(-1,1) translate(-252,-48.7)" />
                                <path d="M124.99998474121094,25.63152313232422 A24.357080459594727,24.368465423583984 0 0 1 146.0932159423828,37.81575393676758 "
                                      stroke="url(#redyel)"  />
                                <path d="M146.0932159423828,37.81575393676758 A24.357080459594727,24.368465423583984 0 0 1 146.0932159423828,62.18423271179199 "
                                      stroke="url(#yelgre)"  />
                                <path d="M146.0932159423828,62.18423271179199 A24.357080459594727,24.368465423583984 0 0 1 124.99998474121094,74.36847496032715 "
                                      stroke="url(#grecya)"  />
                                <path d="M124.99998474121094,74.36847496032715 A24.357080459594727,24.368465423583984 0 0 1 103.90676879882812,62.18423271179199 "
                                      stroke="url(#cyablu)"  />
                                <path d="M103.90676879882812,62.18423271179199 A24.357080459594727,24.368465423583984 0 0 1 103.90676879882812,37.81575393676758 "
                                      stroke="url(#blumag)" />
                                <path d="M103.90676879882812,37.81575393676758 A24.357080459594727,24.368465423583984 0 0 1 124.99998474121094,25.63152313232422 "
                                      stroke="url(#magred)"  />
                            </g>
<defs>
                        <linearGradient id="redyel" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" x1="0" y1="0" x2="1" y2="1">
                            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#23B26D" stop-opacity="0.3"/>
                            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#23B26D" stop-opacity="0.41"/>
                        </linearGradient>
                        <linearGradient id="yelgre" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0"
                                        y2="1">
                            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#23B26D" stop-opacity="0.41"/>
                            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#23B26D" stop-opacity="0.52"/>
                        </linearGradient>
                        <linearGradient id="grecya" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" x1="1" y1="0" x2="0"
                                        y2="1">
                            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#23B26D" stop-opacity="0.52"/>
                            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#23B26D" stop-opacity="0.63"/>
                        </linearGradient>
                        <linearGradient id="cyablu" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" x1="1" y1="1" x2="0"
                                        y2="0">
                            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#23B26D" stop-opacity="0.63"/>
                            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#23B26D" stop-opacity="0.74"/>
                        </linearGradient>
                        <linearGradient id="blumag" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" x1="0" y1="1" x2="0"
                                        y2="0">
                            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#23B26D" stop-opacity="0.74"/>
                            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#23B26D" stop-opacity="0.85"/>
                        </linearGradient>
                        <linearGradient id="magred" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" x1="0" y1="1" x2="1"
                                        y2="0">
                            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#23B26D" stop-opacity="0.85"/>
                            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#23B26D" stop-opacity="1"/>
                        </linearGradient>
                        <linearGradient id="lgrad" x1="100%" y1="50%" x2="0%" y2="50%">
                            <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,255,255);stop-opacity:0"/>
                            <stop offset="60%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,255,255);stop-opacity:1"/>
                            <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,255,255);stop-opacity:1"/>
                        </linearGradient>
                        <linearGradient id="rgrad" x1="0%" y1="50%" x2="100%" y2="50%">
                            <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,255,255);stop-opacity:0"/>
                            <stop offset="60%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,255,255);stop-opacity:1"/>
                            <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,255,255);stop-opacity:1"/>
                        </linearGradient>
                    </defs>
```

https://codepen.io/scvsoft-marianovicente/pen/abmrdXo

It looks good enough, but now, I have small spaces between each element. (Depending on the browser in some places looks more visible than others).

[image: spaces]

I tried to apply a distortion/blur. to hide that but affects all borders.
It is possible to hide this spaces?

Comment: you may try to use [shape-rendering="crispEdges"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/shape-rendering)

Comment: Alter your shapes so that their borders overlap by a tiny amount.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau can you provide an example?

Comment: @enxaneta crispEdges seems to fix the issue, but destroy all possible quality

Comment: @vmariano At the moment the adjacent segments of the circle butt up against one another (the edges coincide).  Instead change each join so that one of the edges extends a bit further and overlaps its neighbour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try an annealing filter (dilate/erode). See if it solves your issues.

```
<svg class="streak-animation" viewbox="0 0 250 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <filter id="anneal">
      <feMorphology operator="dilate" radius="1" />
      <feMorphology operator="erode" radius="1" /> 
    </filter>
  </defs>
     <g class="all-streaks" filter="url(#anneal)">
```

More details - as requested:

- The feMorphology filter replaces every pixel's R,G,B and A values with the maximum (dilate) or minimum (erode) value of those color channels in a 2*radius. For simple monochrome shapes, this effectively adds (or subtracts) a one pixel outline around the shape.
- In this case, the dilate fills in  the super thin lines between shapes (and adds a 1px border around the whole shape). But then when you do an erode, there is no longer any semi-transparent pixels between the shapes to supply a low alpha value to erode, so only the 1px outline around the whole shape is removed.

Comment: Works perfect. if you can add details of how it works this I think would improve the question.

Comment: Sorry for the last minute update: Works well but in chrome creates a glitch over the borders. :(. I guess will be fix on the future.

Comment: It creates a glitch in your checkmark - but the arc segments are fine. So, throw a g element with the filter around the arc segments.