# How to properly convert Figma conic (aka radial) gradients to android vector drawable?

Tags: android, android-layout, svg, android-vectordrawable, radial-gradients

I am having trouble creating an android vector drawable as shown in Figma.
Here how the image looks like:

[image: gradient]

It's a rectangle that uses a combination of 3 gradients as a background. The Figma code looks like this:

Properties

```
height: 474px;
width: 312px;
left: 32px;
top: 170px;
border-radius: 8px;
```

Colors:

```
background-blend-mode: screen;
background: conic-gradient(from 180deg at 50% 50%, #FFFFFF -9.78deg, #000000 9.35deg, #FFFFFF 69.37deg, #000000 121.87deg, #FFFFFF 161.25deg, #000000 202.5deg, #FFFFFF 245.62deg, #000000 303.75deg, #FFFFFF 350.22deg, #000000 369.35deg);
background: conic-gradient(from 180deg at 50% 50%, #FFFFFF -22.26deg, #000000 27.81deg, #FFFFFF 81.58deg, #000000 116.79deg, #FFFFFF 158.7deg, #000000 216.69deg, #FFFFFF 262.5deg, #000000 307.09deg, #FFFFFF 337.74deg, #000000 387.81deg);
background: linear-gradient(151.68deg, #1DC4BD 0.54%, rgba(217, 240, 66, 0.981193) 17.64%, rgba(248, 165, 253, 0.893164) 42.5%, rgba(162, 172, 249, 0.951971) 60.11%, rgba(60, 244, 147, 0.59) 83.94%, #3DBEF0 100%);
```

CSS code (Android code doesn't work correct):

```
position: absolute;
width: 312px;
height: 474px;
left: 32px;
top: 170px;

background: conic-gradient(from 180deg at 50% 50%, #FFFFFF -9.78deg, #000000 9.35deg, #FFFFFF 69.37deg, #000000 121.87deg, #FFFFFF 161.25deg, #000000 202.5deg, #FFFFFF 245.62deg, #000000 303.75deg, #FFFFFF 350.22deg, #000000 369.35deg), conic-gradient(from 180deg at 50% 50%, #FFFFFF -22.26deg, #000000 27.81deg, #FFFFFF 81.58deg, #000000 116.79deg, #FFFFFF 158.7deg, #000000 216.69deg, #FFFFFF 262.5deg, #000000 307.09deg, #FFFFFF 337.74deg, #000000 387.81deg), linear-gradient(151.68deg, #1DC4BD 0.54%, rgba(217, 240, 66, 0.981193) 17.64%, rgba(248, 165, 253, 0.893164) 42.5%, rgba(162, 172, 249, 0.951971) 60.11%, rgba(60, 244, 147, 0.59) 83.94%, #3DBEF0 100%);
background-blend-mode: screen, difference, normal;
opacity: 0.5;
border-radius: 8px;
```

figma code as image: [design tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Naiu2.png), [inspect tab 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/adUxJ.png), [inspect tab 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/adUxJ.png)

Can you please draw such a design as an android vector drawable (aka `.xml` file)?

I've tried many ways (svg, manually, ...) but could not draw it as shown in Figma. The best result I've achieved was [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7I96.png) view with [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ECTPByAIziJcBY8-_BccTrZxFpY3q7fY/view?usp=sharing) source code. I can add additional information if you need

Answer (score 1):

It seems SVGs don't have standard support for angular or conic gradients, which is why you're having trouble creating an android vector drawable of that type. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2465405/svg-angular-gradient).

CSS only recently got that feature which explained why the exported CSS code you got is working.
I would suggest you try one of the CSS to SVG converters online ([here's an example](https://www.kmhcreative.com/pages/css3-2-svg/)) and see if that works. Otherwise, you might have to export the gradient in another format to use in your app.

Comment: https://www.kmhcreative.com/pages/css3-2-svg/ >> "Sorry, this content is not available in your country."

Comment: Oh. Well, you can do a Google search for CSS to SVG converters and find one that works in your country. Alternatively, you can use a VPN.
Here's another I just saw: https://sendeyo.com/onlineconverter/en/css/svg

Comment: Thank you for the reply!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, checked the SVG converter you've provided, unfortunately, it didn't work. For now, I am using webp (instead of android vector drawable) in the project. But let's leave the question open, maybe someone can draw such gradients using SVG or another resizable format

Comment: Alright, that's cool. 