# Applying radialGradient to stroke of a spinner

Tags: css, svg

I am trying to implement the below spinner shown in the figure. Please find the svg code exported from the design file below.
However when I try to use the exported code, the svg is invisible, meaning it renders but does not display the stroke/circle.

[image]

```
<svg width="21" height="21" viewBox="0 0 21 21" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path 
 d="M20 10.5C20 5.25329 15.7467 1 10.5 1C5.25329 1 1 5.25329 1 10.5C1 15.7467 5.25329 20 10.5 20" 
 stroke="url(#paint0_angular_666_32)" 
 stroke-width="2"
 stroke-linecap="round"
/>
<defs>
<radialGradient 
 id="paint0_angular_666_32"  
 cx="0"
 cy="0"
 r="1"
 gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" 
 gradientTransform="translate(10.5 10.5) rotate(90) scale(9.5)"
>
 <stop/> 
 <stop offset="0.765625" stop-opacity="0"/>
</radialGradient>
</defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: if you want a CSS solution: https://css-loaders.com/spinner/#l13

Comment: I think you're looking for a conic gradient (that SVG doesn't have). There are questions on how to [fake one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2465405/svg-angular-gradient) though.

Answer (score 0):

This is the "fake" conic gradient. It is pretty hard to make precise in black/white. When using colors it is easier to hide that is is just linear gradients all the way.

```css
body {
  background-color: Wheat;
}

#spinner {
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }

  to {
    transform: rotate(-360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="95vh" viewBox="0 0 120 120">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="lg1" x1="-20" x2="0" y1="20" y2="-20"
      gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="rotate(18)">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#000"/>
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#444"/>
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="lg2" x1="-20" x2="0" y1="20" y2="-20"
      gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="rotate(18)">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#444"/>
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#888"/>
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="lg3" x1="-20" x2="0" y1="20" y2="-20"
      gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="rotate(18)">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#888"/>
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#ccc"/>
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="lg4" x1="-20" x2="0" y1="20" y2="-20"
      gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="rotate(18)">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#ccc"/>
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#fff"/>
    </linearGradient>
    <mask id="m1">
      <circle r="54" stroke="white" stroke-width="12" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-dasharray="270 360" stroke-dashoffset="-20" pathLength="360" />
    </mask>
    <mask id="m2">
      <g stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="25" mask="url(#m1)">
       <rect width="60" height="60" fill="url(#lg4)" transform="rotate(0) skewX(19)" />
       <rect width="60" height="60" fill="url(#lg3)" transform="rotate(70) skewX(19)" />
       <rect width="60" height="60" fill="url(#lg2)" transform="rotate(140) skewX(19)" />
       <rect width="60" height="60" fill="url(#lg1)" transform="rotate(210) skewX(19)" />
      </g>
    </mask>
    <mask id="m3">
      <rect width="60" height="60" fill="white"
        transform="translate(0 0) rotate(0) skewX(30)" />
      <circle r="60" fill="red"/>
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <g transform="translate(60 60)">
    <rect id="spinner" x="-60" y="-60" width="120" height="120"
      fill="black" mask="url(#m2)"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```